# Positive definite matrices: minor criteria vs quadratic form

Tags: matrices, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-forms, positive-definite

Let $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -8\\ 
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Clearly $\Delta _1>0$ and $\Delta _2 >0$. Hence, we can say that $A$ is positive definite .

But there are $X=\begin{pmatrix}
x & y 
\end{pmatrix}\neq 0 $ such that $X^T \cdot AX <0$

EX : $X=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$

Does this contradict the fact that $A$ is positive definite according to minor criteria?

Comment: Your $A$ is not symmetric..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, Calculon is right. More precisely, we can give the following definition: $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is $\geq 0$ IFF for every vector $x$, $x^TAx\geq 0$. This is equivalent to $A+A^T$ is symmetric $\geq 0$.

On the other hand, the test using the principal minors is valid only when  the considered matrix is symmetric. Here, $\det(A+A^T)<0$...